# Confused regarding the answer of a problem based on locus.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, factoring, locus

I have a question on locus which goes like this.
$A(5,3)$ and $B(3,-2)$ are two fixed points. Find the equation of the locus of $P$, so that the triangle $PAB$ is 9.
Now the loci of the point $P$ should be 2 parallel lines on either side of $AB$. So we get equations of two lines. 
One is $5x-2y-37$ and other is $5x-2y-1$. 
The answer in answer key is the locus of $P$ lies on $(5x-2y-37)(5x-2y-1)=0$
But I don't understand why shouldn't we present the answer as, the loci of point P are lines with equations $5x-2y-37$ and $5x-2y-1$.
Why do we write them as factors? 
Hope my question is clear.

Comment: That groups the two lines in a single equation (that of a degenerate conic).

Comment: Is my way of writing wrong or is it that this grouping of 2 lines into a single equation is more correct way of representing?

Comment: $5x−2y−37$ is an expression, not an equation.  $5x−2y−37=0$ is an equation.  The distinction is important.

Comment: Yep will take care of that. I do write it as an equation on paper though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is almost correct except you should say "one is $5x-2y-37 \bf= 0$ and ....".

You have the right to give your answer in two separate equations or equivalently in the way presented in the answer key. It is a form called system of equations or pair of equations. It bundled two equations together.

Comment: Yeah of course I do equate it with zero on paper...I just was not very meticulous here, sorry about that.  What I don't understand is if one equation represents one line; then how does their product make sense on graph? They are parallel here in this case.

Comment: @NiketParikh Let do the explanation backward. (5x−2y−37)(5x−2y−1) = 0 means (5x−2y−37) = 0 or (5x−2y−1) = 0 which is your answer. System of equations or pair of equations is a more advanced topic you probably will come across in a later stage.

Answer (score 1):

$(5x−2y−37)(5x−2y−1)=0 \quad \iff \quad 5x−2y−37=0 \quad {\rm or} \quad 5x−2y−1=0$.

The former equation is a more compact, albeit cute, way of expressing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A locus represents the set of points that fulfill a specific condition, often expressed using a so-called implicit equation like
$$f(x,y)=0.$$

If your analysis reveals that there are two separate cases, you can express the locus with a logical disjunction, as

$$f(x,y)=0\lor g(x,y)=0.$$

But this is equivalent to saying that the product is zero:

$$f(x,y)\cdot g(x,y)=0,$$

which is also of the form
$$h(x,y)=0.$$

Mostly a matter of taste.